# Evaluating $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot\ln\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$

Tags: limits

I know the value of the limit is $-\dfrac{1}{6}$. I tried to use the fact

$$\ln(ab)=\ln(a)+\ln(b)$$

to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot\ln\left(n\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\cdot\left(\ln(n)+\ln\left(\sin\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)\right)$$

However, I don't think this is the best way to solve it. I also thought about using the fundamental limit
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{n}}=0$$

But as it's multiplied by $n^2$, I can't see how is it useful.

Comment: $$
\log \left( {n\sin \left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)} \right) = \log \left( {n\left( {\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{{6n^3 }} +  \cdots } \right)} \right) = \log \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }} +  \cdots } \right) =  - \frac{1}{{6n^2 }} +  \cdots 
$$

Comment: Perhaps the best aproach is to expand $\sin$ as a Taylor series or, if you dont know about taylor, to use l'hopital.

Comment: Your limit is equivalent to $\frac{\sin x -x }{x^3}$, for $x\to 0$, which one many times discussed on this site.

Comment: @Gary why did $\log$ disappear in the last equality?

Comment: $\log(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\ldots$ for $-1<x<1$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_series).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use
$$\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{\ln(y+1)}{y}=1$$
Letting $y=n\sin \frac{1}{n}-1$
So $$n^2\ln (n\sin\frac{1}{n})=n^2(n\sin \frac{1}{n}-1)\frac{\ln(n\sin \frac{1}{n})}{n\sin \frac{1}{n}-1}$$ so the limit is replaced by

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2(n\sin \frac{1}{n}-1)$$ and as remarked this is an application of
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x -x}{x^3}$$